# Whats the easiest way to add custom style to the module parameters form at the admin in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

My simple module using 3 field, 2 text input and a tinymce textarea, but the textarea looks broken. http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/8648/joomla464.jpg

This is my config:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="moduleclass_sfx" type="text" default="" label="Module Class Suffix" description="PARAMMODULECLASSSUFFIX" />
            <field name="url" type="text" default="" label="Paste the url" description="" />
            <field style="clear:both;float:left;background-color:red;" name="description" type="editor" default="default" rows="20" cols="40" />            
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

ty

Comment: Never actually tried it, but have you tried using class instead of style for that field, and work with it from there?

Comment: maybe try adding `clear:both;` to the url field

Comment: joomla lookes like to drop these

Answer (score 0):

You could add your css to

administrator/templates/bluestork/css/template.css (That is if your using the default administration template)

but there is a risk when joomla updates you will lose your css... you could alwasy copiy the template... give it a diffrent name and update the css there. so your copie wont be affected by any joomla update.

so adding your css there you just need to use the right css selector.

Otherwise i would use an artical selector or category selector

```
            <field
                name="category_id"
                type="category"
                description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_CATEGORIES_CHOOSE_CATEGORY_DESC"
                extension="com_content"
                label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_CATEGORIES_CHOOSE_CATEGORY_LABEL"
                show_root="true"
                required="true" />
```

And put what ever content you need in an artical.. you dont have much room to put the editor on the right for the modules configurations anyway.